# Selecting a nested input tag retrieves jQuery object but all attributes undefined

Tags: jquery

As requested, I created a jsFiddle example to show this in action:
https://jsfiddle.net/mthksx3p/36/

Given the following (stripped down) HTML within a table:

```
<table id="aTable">
  <tbody>

    <tr id="editFormula-formulaResource-0" class="editFormula_formulaResource">
      <td>
        <input id="anArrayid[0].field1" name="name1" value="20" type="hidden">
        <input id="anArrayid[0].field2" name="name2" value="1" type="hidden"> 
        Required Count:
        <input id="anArrayid[0].field3" name="name3" value="3" type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" class="jquery-button" id="newRow" value="Add New Row" onClick="addRow()" />
```

Why is the value attribute returning undefined instead of 0 or "0" from within the javascript/ jQuery? (I have since added @GertG's suggestion regarding the illegal characters, it now works in jsFiddle).

```
function addRow() {

      var idx = 1;

      var $resourceCountSelector
      target = "#anArrayid\\[" + String(idx - 1) + "\\]\\.field3";          
      $resourceCountSelector = $(target);
      alert(target);
      alert($resourceCountSelector);
      alert($resourceCountSelector.attr("value"));

      return;
      //code that was removed is the code that does the cloning, but as the issue reproduces without it, I left it out as extraneous.

    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Note: Firefox 46.0.1 on Mac 10.7.5
I saw some other explanations that appear wonky, so perhaps it is a browser/platform thing? Seems like this is so basic though, I can select other tags fine. #jQueryNoob.

Comment: Are you executing your code before the elements exist in the page? Is your code within a document ready call or at the end of the page?

Comment: Ahh... this is just after I have cloned an element (added a new row via clone of previous row). The row shows up on my browser though, so it should be there?

Comment: This code is inside a function being called when the user pressed an "Add New Row" button, BTW.

Comment: Post a [mcve] please so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: In the future you should know that jQuery's `.attr()` value is the value when the document has loaded and so you should use `.val()` in order to get the dynamic value that changes when the input box is changed.

Comment: @BubbleHacker - just so you know, the same behavior occurs with val()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although brackets and periods are perfectly valid in html ids, they have special meanings in jQuery selectors, so you need to escape them with double backslashes.

```
target = "#anArrayid\\[" + String(idx - 1) + "\\]\\.field3";
```

Comment: Interesting - thank you. I had tried a single \ to escape, did not realize \\ was needed. But even after that change, it still returns undefined. :-/

Comment: Bad DeadPool!! Nope, I forgot to escape the "." - it works. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1):

The "[brackets]" are not a valid character for id attribute... It should end up being the content of `anArrayid[0].field3` array field, so if it is the data in that array, what you try to assign in `target = "#anArrayid[" + String(idx - 1) + "].field3";` it should be something like `target = "#"+anArrayid[idx - 1].field3;`.

Comment: This is a Grails / GSP syntax for auto binding session data to controller. It's sweet, but this is causing issues. I tried @GertG's suggestion of a double \\ escape, but that also does not work.

Comment: Well jQuery execute it self on client side over the rendered DOM, so you may want to check if the Grails / GSP syntax for auto binding session data to controller, executes also on client side, if it doesn't then you can't use it to call elements with jQuery, because the elements will have the value of the field inside the array, not the array...field name.

Comment: This works now, as expected. The issue was that i did not realize I had to escape the characters \\. \\[ \\]